# How to fix "event.bind is not a function"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm setting up a new Discord server, so that means I need to make a new custom bot for it. I was redoing the index.js code and then I try starting it up for the first time and it is telling me "event.bind is not a function"? Where is the issue and how do I resolve it?

I have tried reinstalling Node.js, Enmap, and Discord.js but the problem keeps reoccurring.

```
fs.readdir("./events/", (err, files) => {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  files.forEach(file => {
    const event = require(`./events/${file}`);
    const eventName = file.split(".")[0];
    client.on(eventName, event.bind(null, client));
  });
});
```

Comment: Please identify for which value (and type) of `file` and `event` you get this error.

Comment: are you sure that every file in the `events` folder exports a function called `bind`? Maybe you could check if `event.bind()` is defined before trying to call it.

Comment: The exports in events call client, message, and args

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your message.js is
`module.exports = (client, message) => {`

The code is from https://anidiots.guide/first-bot/a-basic-command-handler#main-file-changes so you might find more there.

Additionally, the loader is not checking if the file is a .js file, so make sure to only have .js files in the folder.

Comment: This does not work, my script already looked like this and even when I redid the whole script I still get the same error
client.on(eventName, event.bind(null, client));
TypeError: event.bind is not a function at files.forEach.file(C:\Users\warri\Desktop\Paralyss\index.js:13:32)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at fs.readdir (C:\Users\warri\Desktop\Paralyss\index.js:10:9)
at FSReqCallback.args [as oncomplete] (fs.js:146:20)
PS C:\Users\warri\Desktop\Paralyss>

Comment: Are you sure that there are only .js files in the events folder